# Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página em JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirecionamento-de-url

Gostaria de saber quais os métodos de redirecionamento existentes em Javascript, e também utilizando jQuery, e se possível, gostaria de saber todos eles.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Neste caso o jQuery não é preciso.
A solução passa por javascript simples.
**Ficam aqui duas opções:**

*Opção 1:*

```
window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
// ou uma variante com o mesmo efeito
window.location.assign("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

*Opção 2:*

```
window.location.replace("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

A diferença entre estes dois métodos é que o primeiro faz com que seja possivel clickar para trás na história do browser e ir para a página anterior. O segundo substituí a pagina atual e ao clickar para ir para trás na história, a página inicial não está acessível (foi substituída na história).

---

Se quiser que o utilizador abra **uma janela nova** (sem perder a janela de origem), pode usar:

```
window.open("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

Este método [**window.open()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) permite também passar parâmetros/opções como o tamanho, conteudo, etc.

Comment: ótima resposta, irei marcar como correta.

Comment: `location.replace` é otimo (prevenindo o `history.back`) para áreas com autenticação, prevenindo o usuário de voltar a tela de login sem desconectar. E também é muito útil em aplicativos que usam webViews (exemplo: ios, android). +1 para a sua resposta!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, bom exemplo, concordo plenamente.

Answer (score 9):

Via jQuery (apenas para conhecimento se for o seu desejado)

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://www.sitedesejado.com');
```

Entretanto, conforme já foi mencionado, não é necessário jQuery para realizar redirecionamento.

Comment: Value mencionar que `.prop()`/`.attr()` são designados a trabalhar com elementos do DOM somente. Passar outros tipos de objetos é pedir para ter dor de cabeça no futuro. `=]`

Answer (score 8):

Com javascript mesmo:

```
window.location.href = "http://seusite.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

Como mencionado acima basta utilizar o comando:

```js
window.location="http://seusite.com";
```

não necessidade do `href`, minimizando seu código.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.location is not a function