# Jquery não direciona para outra página

Tags: jquery

Tenho um site do qual consta alguns botões. Ao clicar nos botões, são direcionados para as respectivas páginas, porém tem um botão do qual não direciona, apenas permanece na mesma página. O código que estou usando para ele é:

```
    $('#btnSeguroViagem').on("click",function()
          {
              var novaURL = "seguro-viagem.php";
              $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);
          });
<button type="submit" name="Submit" id="btnSeguroViagem" value="Solicitar"  class="btn btn-danger btn-small"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Solicitar Seguro Viagem</button>
```

Alguém sabe me informar o porque esse cara não está indo? A página existe, retirei todo o conteúdo e coloquei uma frase, mas nada. Ao clicar no botão, dá o post, mas permanece na mesma página e não direciona para a página seguro-viagem.php. O estranho é que já dei um alert() dentro da chamada e chega corretamente.

Comment: Boa noite, reverti a pergunta pra original, Jose não se coloca a resposta na pergunta, pra criar uma resposta clique no botão responder.

Comment: Certo Guilherme... vou criar a resposta.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo encontrar o botão para responder.

Comment: Boa tarde Jose, questões fechadas não tem botão responder, como a sua pergunta foi um erro de digitação, portanto não é necessário uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso o jQuery não é preciso.
A solução passa por javascript simples.
Ficam aqui duas opções:

Opção 1:

```
window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
// ou uma variante com o mesmo efeito
window.location.assign("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

Opção 2:

```
window.location.replace("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

A diferença entre estes dois métodos é que o primeiro faz com que seja possivel clickar para trás na história do browser e ir para a página anterior. O segundo substituí a pagina atual e ao clickar para ir para trás na história, a página inicial não está acessível (foi substituída na história).

---

Se quiser que o utilizador abra uma janela nova (sem perder a janela de origem), pode usar:

```
window.open("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

Este método window.open() permite também passar parâmetros/opções como o tamanho, conteudo, etc.

---

Fonte: [Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página em JavaScript/jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/como-redirecionar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina-em-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Certo Leonardo, mas o código que tenho, usa Jquery, pois estou usando as abas em Jquery.

Comment: O que é estranho, que mesmo colocando outras páginas, ele não direciona.

Comment: Se seus links estiverem usando `#` pode ser o problema, não?

Comment: Perdoe-me colegas. O erro está no tipo do botão. Estou usando o Submit, em vez do button. Ao usar o Submit, ele dá um post na página. Troquei o Submit por Button e funcionou. Mente cansa. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de você já ter encontrado a sua resposta, acredito que existam vários caminhos mais simples para obter o resultado esperado.

## A

Como você já está fazendo uso do [`Bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons), segue uma informação disponível na página do próprio *framework*:

> Use the button classes on an < a > , < button >, or < input > element.

Isso significa que você pode criar uma tag `a` como o mesmo visual de um `button`. Exemplo:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="seguro-viagem.php">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Solicitar Seguro Viagem
</a>
```

Utilizando a tag `a`, você ainda tem o benefício de poder utilizar o atributo [`target`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

## FORM

Com a tag `form` você pode chamar a URL desejada utilizando o atributo [`action`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp). Exemplo:

```
<form action="seguro-viagem.php">
    <button type="submit" value="Solicitar" class="btn btn-danger btn-small">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Solicitar Seguro Viagem
    </button>
</form>
```

## Javascript

Através do `javascript` você consegue acessar um objeto da janela chamado [`location`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp). Esse objeto possui uma propriedade chamada `href`, que tem como valor o endereço da janela atual. Alterando essa propriedade, você redireciona o cliente para um novo endereço. Exemplo:

```
location.href = 'seguro-viagem.php';
```