# Redirecionar após receber response do servidor?

Tags: node.js, session, login, autenticação, vue.js

Tenho uma aplicação que o front-end é VueJS/Quasar e o servidor é hapiJS. Estou trabalhando na parte de login e gostaria de saber como fazer para redirecionar a página depois de receber a confirmação do servidor de que os dados informados no login estão corretos.

Servidor:

```
server.route({
    path: '/login',
    method: 'post',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        let user = request.query.login;
        let pass = request.query.senha;

        let pesquisa = {'usuario': {$eq: user}, 'senha': {$eq: pass}};

        db.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
            mongoclient.collection('login', function (err, collection) {
                collection.find(pesquisa).toArray(function (err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        mongoclient.close()
                    } else {
                        if (results === pesquisa) {
                            console.log('Login correto');
                            mongoclient.close();
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Cliente:

```
entrar () {
    let self = this
    axios({
      url: '/server/login',
      method: 'post',
      params: self.pessoa
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.$route.router.go(response.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

O que devo mandar na response do servidor para o cliente???
Como redirecionar a página no cliente após receber os dados do servidor??

Comment: Ve se isso aqui te ajuda.
[link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/como-redirecionar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina-em-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Ajuda sim, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será necessário configurar um Router para o seu app front-end.
O mais usado em aplicações Vue.js é o [Vue-Router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router)

Após ter configurado o router, basta usar o comando:

```
this.$router.push('/caminho/desejado')
```

Por exemplo, no seu contexto, deve ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
.then(function (response) {
  // fazer alguma coisa com a resposta do servidor,
  // por exemplo, setar em algum componente que o usuário X está logado
  this.$router.push('/home')
})
```