# Mensagem Bootstrap, aplicar location.reload ao finalizar mensagem

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Boa tarde, estou tentando aplicar `location.reload` no final de uma messagebox após o efeito `.remove()` de 2 segundos mas não estou familiarizado com o `javascript` alguém poderia me auxiliar no código:

```js
function ShowMessage(message, messagetype, icon) {
  var cssclass;
  switch (messagetype) {
    case 'Success':
      cssclass = 'alert-success'
      break;
    case 'Error':
      cssclass = 'alert-danger'
      break;
    case 'Atenção':
      cssclass = 'alert-warning'
      break;
    default:
      cssclass = 'alert-info'
  }
  $('#alert_container').append(
    '<div id="alert_div" style="margin: 0 0.5%; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px #999;" class="alert fade in ' + cssclass + '" ><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><label class="' + icon + '"></label><strong>' + messagetype + '!</strong> <span>' + message + '</span></div > ');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#alert_div").fadeTo(500, 0).slideDown(500, function() {
      $("#alert_div").remove();
    });
  }, 2000); //<- aplicar aqui o refresh, ao desaparecer a mensagem
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  ShowMessage(" Excluido com sucesso!", 'Success', "icon fa fa-check");
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' .messagealert {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  left: 35%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="messagealert" id="alert_container">
</div>
```

Code-behind C#:

```
public enum MessageType { Success, Error, Info, Warning };
```

Função:

```
public void ShowMessage(string Message, MessageType type, string icon)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
        System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        "ShowMessage('" + Message + "','" + type + "', '" + icon + "');", true);
}
```

Chamando a função:

```
ShowMessage(" Excluido com sucesso!", MessageType.Success, "icon fa fa-check");
```

Comment: inclua o html e css

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Incluído

Comment: o seu exemplo não abre a mensagem

Comment: @LeandroAngelo desculpas, eu chamo a mensagem via code-behind c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionar o código abaixo de:

```
$("#alert_div").remove();
// Redireciona
window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
```

Há varias maneiras de redirecionamento, veja mais nessa pergunta: [Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página em JavaScript/jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312)

> [Reversão de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/273673/revisions)

Comment: ao encerrar os 2 segundos da mensagem a pagina fica em loop atualizando. Ela tem que atualizar uma vez apenas

Comment: Como você esta chamando sua função ? Após salvar informações no banco ? Faça um redirecionamento em para ver: `window.location.href = "coloque o endereço aqui";`

Comment: sim, após executar um delete, chamo a mensagem via code-behind C#, a mensagem aparece dizendo que foi excluido após 2 segundos ela desaparece... quando ela desaparece preciso dar um refresh na pagina

Comment: redirecionado window.location.href = "coloque o endereço aqui"; ficou bom obrigado!

Comment: Eu tinha respondido assim no começo, ai quando eu li **reload** eu editei a resposta **:D**

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um redirecionamento conforme comentário de wmsouza, funcionou como queria obrigado!

```
    setTimeout(function () {                
        $("#alert_div").fadeTo(500, 0).slideDown(500, function () {
            $("#alert_div").remove(); 
            window.location.href = "/Views/Default.aspx";
        });               
    }, 2000); //= 2 seconds
}
```