# Botão nao direciona para outra página

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

Tenho um botao que quando clicado nele, o localStorage pega o ID dele, aí joga o id para a outra página, mas quando clico no botao ele nao ta direcionando para a outra página, só ta mudando a url para o nome da página que está mais "botao=1".

HTML:

```
<input id="inicio" type="date">
<input id="fim" type="date">
<button onclick="postData();">gerar</button>

<div id="dados">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function postData() {

        var inicio, fim;
        inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
        fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;
        // Default options are marked with *
        fetch('http://api_aqui', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: `inicio=${inicio}&fim=${fim}`
        }).then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
            data: data,
            status: response.status
        })
        ).then(res => { 
            res.data.map(element => {
                console.log(element.PRODUTO)
                console.log(element.ID)
                $('#dados').append(`
                <h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>
                <br>
                <form id="form">
                <button onClick="pegar(this);" name="botao" value="${element.ID}" href="pagina.php">pegar</button>
                <form>
                `)
            })
        })

        )

    }

    function pegar(botao) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('produto', `${botao.value}`)

    }
```

Comment: Já tentou `window.location.href = 'nomedapagina'`? [Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/como-redirecionar-o-usuário-para-outra-página-em-javascript-jquery) pode te ajudar?

Comment: Já tentei e nao vai, talvez seja pq quando clico no botao ele joga o parametro para a url da página que está, aí acaba nao indo pra outra na mesma aba, tive que utilizar o `window.open('nomedapagina'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que quando você utiliza o elemento `button` dentro de um elemento `form` ele automaticamente executa o parâmetro `action` do form, algumas vezes até ignorando as funções nele atribuídas. Porém, seu form não possui esse parâmetro e por default você está realizando um envio via get para a mesma página que você está, é por isso que aparece `paginaatual.html?botao=1`, onde `botao` é o nome do botão do formulário e `1` é o valor dele.

Retire do seu código o elemento `form` e deverá funcionar corretamente:

```
res.data.map(element => {
    console.log(element.PRODUTO)
    console.log(element.ID)
    $('#dados').append(`
    <h3>${element.PRODUTO}</h3>
    <br>
    <button onClick="pegar(this);" name="botao" value="${element.ID}">pegar</button>
    `)
})
```

Mais uma coisa, não existe atributo `href` dentro de um [elemento button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Consegui colocando o `window.open('progress.php');` na seguinte função:

```
    function pegar(botao){
    localStorage.setItem('produto', `${botao.value}`)
    window.open('progress.php');
}
```

Mas ele abre em outra aba do navegador, e não na mesma.