# Código não redireciona para outra página

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo está funcionando, porém no `else` não está redirecionando pra outra página com o `window.location.assign()`.

```
function verifica() {
 if (document.forms[0].email.value.length == 0) {
  alert('Por favor, informe o seu EMAIL.');
  document.frmEnvia.email.focus();

  return false;
 }

 return true;
}

function checarEmail(){
 if( document.forms[0].email.value=="" 
    || document.forms[0].email.value.indexOf('@')==-1 
    || document.forms[0].email.value.indexOf('.')==-1 )
 {
   alert( "Por favor, informe um E-MAIL válido!" );
   return false;
 } else {
   window.location.assign('http://www.example.com')
 }  

}
```

Comment: tentou usar `window.location.replace('<URL>')`?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página em JavaScript/jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/como-redirecionar-o-usu%c3%a1rio-para-outra-p%c3%a1gina-em-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar o `window.location.replace(url)` ou `window.location.href = url;`

Link para referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace