# Direcionar a outro aplicativo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como faço para o usuario ao clicar na na logo ou botão seja direcionado a outro aplicativo
quero fazer uma pagina e colocar uma logo o do ifood e assim q o usuario clicar nela ele e direcionado ao aplicativo ja na pagina do restaurante, como faço isso??

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página em JavaScript/jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/como-redirecionar-o-usu%c3%a1rio-para-outra-p%c3%a1gina-em-javascript-jquery)

Comment: A pergunta está duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3312/como-redirecionar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina-em-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Existem (n) maneiras de fazer isto funcionar.
Vejam um pouco sobre: [DOM].[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/)

Uma dica seria:

```js
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      window.open(`${Link que deseja direcionar}`);
    });
```

Comment: Exatamente existe várias formas de fazer isso. Veja a resposta do colega.// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "http://www.seulink.com";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("http://www.seulink.com");